# Не получается получить ответ с сервиса

Tags: typescript, angular5

Сервис:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewServiceService {

  private response:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getResponse(userName) {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + userName)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.response = response;
        console.log(response.name);
        return this.response;
      });
  }
}
```

Компонент:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NewServiceService } from './new-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less'],
  providers: [NewServiceService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private userName:string = "";
  private response:any;

  constructor(private nss:NewServiceService){

  }

  search(){
    this.response = this.nss.getResponse(this.userName);
    console.log(this.response);
  }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там где `undifined` должен выводиться ответ от сервера. Ответ есть (это видно с вывода имени в сервисе), но при передачу в компонент с ним что то происходит. Что я упускаю?

Comment: зачем вы вообще делаете `return` внутри подписки? это в официальной документации так написано?

Comment: @overthesanity хотел возвратить ответ

Comment: `subscribe` возвращает `Subscription` а не ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе *getResponse* вашего сервиса, напишите `return` вот так:

```
return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + userName)
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.response = response;
    console.log(response.name);
    return this.response;
  });
```

Ошибка не связана ни с angular ни с typescript. Это основы работы с функциями и методами. У вас метод сервиса просто ничего не возвращает, отсюда и *undefined*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ...сам запутался. Подумал что в сабскрпйб ретурн с функции делает